# How to determine capacitor values for common emitter amplifier?

Tags: capacitor

Looking at this circuit:

[image]

I understand that the two capacitors are used to filter DC.

I don't understand how it is possible to know what values (in terms of farads) would be required for these.

Comment: Do you know what load impedance connects to Vout?

Comment: I mean how would we calculate what Capacitor to use there?

Comment: Do you know what load impedance connects to Vout? (again)

Comment: You mean the Rc and Vcc?

Comment: *But I don't understand how it is possible to know what values (in terms of Farads) would be required for these?* Consider the RC network \$R_E\$ and the capacitor parallel with it. At the transition frequency the impedance of both will be the same. What value do you want for that transition frequency? What value has \$R_E\$? Now you can determine the value that the capacitor needs to have.

Comment: @user1140098 do either Rc or Vcc connect to Vout? Do they????? My question is as plain as can be - what load connects to the terminal called Vout. If you don't know then it's not "possible to know what values"

Comment: I guess the question is how would you know the value of capacitor to use when the other items are variables. If Vin is an analog signal to amplify and Vcc is the power supply

Comment: So, based on what you just said (and my hints about the output capacitor), how would you calculate what the input capacitor would be? What do you need to take account of? What isn't shown on the circuit (or your words) that makes it impossible to calculate either even if you had definite values for the components shown? At the moment it is im*possible to know what values (in terms of Farads) would be required for these* components.

Comment: @user1140098 LISTEN to Andy. He knows stuff. He can be a bit annoying but he's known to be helpful on a good day. It's worth persevering with him. We may yet house train him. But, maybe not. (Same goes for me :-) ). || Note that there are THREE capacitors. Not two. All need to be designed. | Andy asked what connected to Vout. He had a reason. Have a look and see. The AC has to pass that way with minimal impediment. The same applies to the connection to Vin. AND even the connection to the emitter.

Comment: Yes, hmm perhaps I am more confused. I guess I understand that the transistor will amplify a mix of AC from the input signal and DC from the power (which causes bias) and then we need to use a capacitor to filter out the DC part before passing it along and perhaps also filter the input signal somewhat. I know how to calculate what transistor and resistors will be needed. And I know the capacitors are necissary, but I don't why you would choose a particular value for any of them.

Comment: What is the impedance of a capacitor to AC signals? What is your lowest frequency of interest? Why am I asking these questions - think about it. You're slowly getting there.

Comment: What is the impedance of a capacitor to AC signals? I guess that is related to frequency of signal and capacitance in farads as related to the forumula on this page. https://www.allaboutcircuits.com/tools/capacitor-impedance-calculator/ Wouldn't we be interested in all frequencies except for 0Hz because 0hz is the DC signal?

Comment: No, because you know it blocks (does its job) at DC and, you know it should do its job at the highest frequency of interest to you so all that remains to consider is the lowest Signal frequency of interest. Try googling low pass RC circuit.

Comment: So if we want all frequencies except DC we should just use the tiniest capacitor possible?

Comment: All capacitors no matter what value block DC. But your lowest frequency of interest might be 10 Hz (close to DC) so, what value should it be, big or small? Go google capacitor reactance and, did you google RC  high pass filters? If so look for formulas. I erred when I said low pass in the previous comment.

Comment: Is the purpose of the capacitor near the source signal to stop the DC power from pushing against the AC source?